# Typescript enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So I have a type with value that is some Enum.
Example:

```
enum TaskStatus {
 COMPLETED
 IN_PROGRESS
 TO_DO
}

type MyFormType {
  status: TaskStatus
}
```

But how should I tell ts that status in MyFormType is a string value of TaskStatus ("0", "1" etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert integer enum types (and integer literal types) to strings using string template types:

```
// "0" | "1" | "2"
type TaskStatusString = `${TaskStatus}`
```

If you want the key names as string literal types, that is also possible:

```
// "COMPLETED" | "IN_PROGRESS" | "TO_DO"
type TaskStatusName = (keyof typeof TaskStatus) & string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgZwNYGUAuc1gVA3gWACgoBhAeQFkAFAGQFEY6ARAGiKgEkA5AfSoCUyAcX50UKNsRhkeTMpIC+RIgHoVUAEQAGDVAA+mgIy6DGgEwaiaAJ4AHYLESoMWBOgBOASxABzKAF4oAAMAElx4ZHRMbAUg5UI1TXJqekYmE01uPkERMRQMjWlZMktCG3tHSJdsLjgIB0CACiRgawB7ADMocuBOyudohABKKAAyKAQ0L18iIA)

Comment: That is very cool. Never knew Typescript was this powerful!

Comment: yeah. but then I am trying to assign dynamically default value of type TaskStatus and have to convert it with toString(). have error "string is not assignable to parameter type '0' | '1' | '2'"

Comment: Convert it with a string template literal instead of calling toString.